# Mostrar solo determinados valores en una ForeignKey de Django

Tags: django-models, django-forms

Estoy intentando hacer algo muy simple conceptualmente, pero no consigo materializarlo en Django.

Tengo una tabla de cuentas bancarias con una ForeignKey a la tabla usuarios de Django.
Tengo otra tabla de presupuestos con una ForeignKey a la tabla de cuentas bancarias.

Desde el ModelForm de los presupuestos se muestra el campo "cuenta" en un selecto, hasta ahí todo bien.

Pero me muestra todos los registros de la tabla cuentas. Lo que intento es que solo muestre los de las cuentas del usuario que lo está ejecutando. El usuario puedo obtenerlo de la sesión, pero no sé cómo limitar los registros de la ForeignKey.

He visto que se puede hacer una subquery en el modelo para los valores, pero en el modelo yo no tengo acceso al usuario que está ejecutando (no hay request.session).

¿Es posible?

Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Añade las clases de los models.py y lo que tengas, para partir de algo, y podamos ayudar. Un saludo.